If the US wishes for de-escalation, why doesn't it provide Israel with only defensive weapons?
There've been several news sources of how the US is trying to get Israel / Hamas / Hezbollah / Iran to de-escalate (example).
On the other hand, Israel has upped the ante several times, most recently with a pre-emptive cross-border strike against Hezbollah.
It seems clear that if the US doesn't want escalation, it wouldn't provide Israel with the weapons to escalate. Why, then, does it continue to sell Israel these weapons? A recent source says the weapons sales include "more than 50 F-15 fighter jets [to be delivered in 2029], Advanced Medium Range Air-to-Air Missiles, or AMRAAMs, 120 mm tank ammunition and high explosive mortars and tactical vehicles", some of which can clearly be used offensively, although most won't be available until 2026. However,

between the start of Gaza war last October and the end of June, the US has transferred at least 14,000 of the MK-84 2,000lb bombs, 6,500 500lb bombs, 3,000 Hellfire precision-guided air-to-ground missiles, 1,000 bunker-buster bombs, 2,600 air-dropped small-diameter bombs and other munitions.

In comparison, at the start of the Russia-Ukraine war, US aid to Ukraine was largely anti-aircraft / anti-tank weapons, which are much more defensive in nature.
I'm looking for an explanation as to why the US that's seeking de-escalation shouldn't/can't provide Israel with similar defensive weapons only.

I don't think anti-tank or anti-aircraft weapons would be of much use to Israel as I don't recall it ever being attacked with tanks or aircraft in the first place. Hamas and Hezbollah seem to mainly use missiles, suicide bombs, and foot soldiers.

@F1Krazy I'm pretty sure antiaircraft weapons can shoot down missiles. https://www.businessinsider.com/ukraine-soldier-appears-down-russia-cruise-missile-incredible-shot-experts-2024-1 From a quick Google search.

What exactly would you consider defensive weapons for the kind of conflict Israel is in? The military strategy of Russia seems hardly comparable to what Israel is facing.

You could ask about specific weapons (e.g. why does Israel need fighter jets), but if you're proposing defensive weapons then be more specific about what you will allow them. Many weapons can be used both offensively and defensively - while the F-15 can be used for ground attacks, it is primarily an air superiority fighter and thus can be used defensively to protect Israeli airspace, and is being used along with air-to-air missiles to shoot down drones.

@StuartF Specifically antiair weapons, then.

@Allure, bombing rockets pointed at your country is also purely defensive and is more reliable and cost effective, than shooting them down in the air.

@Jacob3 however, the latter is likely to be viewed as far less escalatory than the former, by the people who were going to shoot the rockets.

@user20574 that would be an answer, if it can be sourced.

Isn't the ability to be used offensively what defines a thing as being a "weapon"?  Otherwise, it's "armor" or "protection" or something.

Can you say what 'only defensive weapons' might mean? See Dan04, above… or please, say which weapon might be 'only defensive'…

The aircraft (you mentioned) won't be delivered until some years into the future, so you might want to remove those as not the most relevant item during this war. OTOH the thousands of bombs... https://www.theguardian.com/world/article/2024/jul/10/biden-resumes-sending-israel-bombs Not that Israel is short of aircraft currently: they have over 300 US fighter/bomber jets.

Because the best defense is a good offense. Think for a second if Ukraine had the ATACMS etc. to hit the Russian concentrations as they were massing across the border in 2022. Or even as they were struck in that 40-mile (IIRC) convoy. Never mind F-35s. Establishing air supremacy has always been a cornerstone of US and Israeli warfighting doctrine.
A major reason why Israel didn't get overwhelmed by the (usually numerically superior) Arab armies in all the wars past was the technological superiority and nearly unreserved US help with all sorts of weapons.
The US hardly fears Iran etc., so escalation dominance is the preferred strategy there. OTOH with Russia they have to be more cautious, for things not to get nuclear. Whether they were too cautious in what they provided Ukraine is something that historians will probably never settle.

I can't fault you for reading too much into that Reuters piece (I've not located the whole press conference transcript), but if one considers just the bit the Reuters quoted/mention, one might get the wrong impression. I found out the official summary of a more recent exchange of the same kind between SecDef and the Israeli DM (bylined by the same Pentagon Press Secretary):

Secretary Austin highlighted that further escalation is not inevitable and that all countries in the region would benefit from a de-escalation in tensions, including through completing a Gaza ceasefire and hostage release deal. However, he also stressed that the unprecedented scale of U.S. support for Israel since October 7 should leave Iran, Lebanese Hizballah, and other Iranian-backed terrorist groups with no doubt about U.S. resolve.

No Israeli action was publicly called out by the US SecDef other than not finalizing the deal with Hamas, which is assumed will lower the overall temperature in the Middle East. And even for that bit, the public call was not that directed at one side.
While the "however" sentence that follows doesn't have the word 'escalate' in it, it's basically suggesting that the US is determined to win any escalation contest, i.e. it's the classic message of escalation dominance. And the earlier part of the summary that I've not quoted is also about
"future defensive force posture changes, that the Department will take to support the defense of Israel".
Also, the kind of escalation that the US seems most concerned about in Lebanon (according to Axios' sources):

The Biden administration warned Israel that a ground invasion of Lebanon, even if it is only in the areas close to the border, would likely push Iran to intervene, U.S. and Israeli officials said.
One scenario the administration raised with Israel is that Lebanon could be flooded with militants from pro-Iranian militias in Syria, Iraq and even Yemen who would want to join the fighting.

And while the US administration is not encouraging that ground operation (in Lebanon), they don't seem be protesting [e.g.] use of tanks in Gaza. And on that angle:

Israel requested a total of 10,000 120-millimeter Rheinmetall precision rounds in November to replenish ammunition used in the Gaza operation.
Other countries have also received requests, with US President Joe Biden agreeing to deliver 14,000 rounds in early December, bypassing Congress.

(Speaking of Gaza, the US administration did weigh against some weapons in Gaza, in particular 2000 lbs bombs, although 500 lbs ones were okay'd.)

So, in comments, it seem to come down to this proposal: that shooting down rockets after launch would "viewed as far less escalatory by the people who were going to shoot the rockets" than bombing them on the launch site. Sure, it's a gotcha when you put it that way, and so elevates non-escalation to some kind of ultimate pedestal, but telling your own citizens that some of them had to die because you ran out of interceptors against a large attack doesn't balance too well vs telling them some of the attackers had to die with their launchers. If you even need a quote on something like that...

Referring to the death toll from Monday’s strikes, which the Lebanese health ministry says have killed at least 356 people including 24 children and 42 women, Hagari said the casualties included “many terrorists” that “were nearby the weapons.”

Of course, things may be a little different when you're a donor country and it's not your own citizens who are on the line. I suppose you could even make an argument that until recently Ukraine was under some such restrictions, e.g. they could not shoot HIMARS GMLRS over the [pre-war] Russian border, even if they saw some Russian launchers/artillery ready to fire from there. But that kind of super-strong limitation/safeguard against escalation has proven ultimately overbearing and untenable. (Ukraine is still not allowed to shoot ATACMS like that though, AFAIK. These have substantially longer range than GMLRS.)

FWTW, recent events have shown that one can escalate by planting small amounts of explosives in pagers and walkie-talkies (which Hezbollah said crossed "all red lines"). It's hard to see how the US could prevent that by regulating weapons supplies to Israel. True though, Israel's government has only considered that event the opening step of a new phase, and followed through with more air strikes on rocket launchers.
On the broader strategy, it's probably to Israel's advantage to deal a severe blow to Hezbollah before Iran can acquire its first nuclear weapons. And conversely, at least some Western analysts think that Iran is looking to restrain Hezbollah as their insurance card (i.e. not 'waste' most of their rockets and drones beforehand) in case Israel does attack Iran's nuclear facilities. A coordinated missile+drone attack from both Hezbollah and Iran would be harder to fend off than if they come separated in time.
Yeah, the present US administration is verbally calling on all sides for restraint. And the opposition in the shortly upcoming US elections (Trump) keeps saying "none of this would have happened if I were president". YMMV, considering their track record in re Iran. In typical fashion, Trump even claimed that "Israel will cease to exist" if Harris were elected. Iran clearly likes the current administration as the "lesser of two evils" from their standpoint.
Aside from pure game strategy considerations between 'black box' actors in a [neo]realism setting, the US is a democracy with all that entails-- ethnic minorities, lobby groups etc. One politician saying "I don't care what happens to Ukraine" is winning about half the electorate. "I don't care what happens to Israel" isn't much of a winner in US domestic politics.  See e.g. even the Democratic convention's choice of speakers. Or the reception Netanyahu got in Congress.

“Our fight is your fight … Our enemies are your enemies,” Netanyahu said to thunderous applause.

N.B. He actually added that the faster Israel wins in Gaza, the faster a broader war will be prevented in the Middle East. I guess the corollary to that is that the faster Israel wins against Hezbollah... It's called "defeat in detail".
BTW, when some politicians linked to the present US administration made some suggestions that Netanyahu was interested in prolonging conflict, they received immediate pushback that they're not respecting the democratic choices of the Israelis. And early September polls indicated that the Israeli public wanted more action in Lebanon:

67% of Jewish respondents thought Israel should intensify its response to Hezbollah.

The withholding of (large) bombs by the Biden administration at one point (in the spring) also received pushback from inside and outside the Democratic party. So, the Biden administration has little room to maneuver, and is bound to mostly limit themselves to generic exhortations about not wanting a broader war.

Biden has also released a statement after Monday's peak of IDF air strikes (in Lebanon):

I’ve been briefed on the latest developments in Israel and in Lebanon. My team is in constant contact with their counterparts, and we’re working to deescalate in a way that allows people to return to their home safely.

It's a bit ambiguous, but not too hard not read that as a faint applause to Gallant's statement:

“Today is a significant peak — on this day we have taken out of order tens of thousands of rockets and precise munitions. What Hezbollah has built over a period of 20 years since the second Lebanon War is in fact being destroyed by the IDF,” Yoav Gallant said.

Yeah, this has been seized on by critics as "de-escalation through escalation".
Or slightly more succinctly "escalate to deescalate". (OTOH Hezbollah too has been accused of using this same strategy, earlier on, when they attacked Israel's north in response to the events in Gaza.)
Also, returning people to their homes (in the north) has been a stated objective of Israel's operations.

“I already said, we will bring back the residents of the north safely to their homes, and this is exactly what will do,” Netanyahu said in a video statement.

By the way, although it happened some days earlier, there a few massive explosions at Russian ammunition depots, deep in their territory, reportedly due to Ukrainian drone strikes. Although the US doesn't want to be the direct provider of the weapons causing these for now, they're not complaining that those explosions are any sort of escalation either, AFAICT.

It's also worth recalling in this context the (unsuccessful) US plan, as reported this summer:

[US envoy Amos] Hochstein seeks to broker a ceasefire deal that will relocate Hezbollah forces approximately 7 kilometres north of the border—roughly to the Litani River—and deploy several thousand Lebanese Armed Forces soldiers in their place. Concurrently, according to the plan, Israel would end its manned and unmanned overflights of Lebanon.
[...] Despite the ostensible benefits to both sides, however, Hochstein’s initiative doesn’t appear to be gaining traction. Timing is a big part of the problem. Hezbollah doesn’t want a full-scale war but is committed to continuing its performative resistance campaign against Israel until a formal Israel-Hamas ceasefire is reached.
In the absence of a Gaza ceasefire and as September fast approaches, Israel is escalating in Lebanon. Senior and other prominent Hezbollah commanders are being killed on an almost daily basis. Hezbollah, too, is pushing the envelope, recently flying reconnaissance drones over Haifa and targeting Israeli towns as far south as in the lower Galilee.

Thus far only anonymous officials (a staple of the Biden administration PR strategy, in general) were willing to criticize the latest intensification of the Israeli operations:

Israeli officials have said the recent uptick in airstrikes on Hezbollah targets in Lebanon was designed to force the Iran-aligned group to agree to a diplomatic solution.
But the U.S. State Department official, briefing reporters in New York on condition of anonymity, pushed back on this Israeli position, saying President Joe Biden's administration was focused on "reducing tensions ... and breaking the cycle of strike-counterstrike."
"I can't recall, at least in recent memory, a period in which an escalation or intensification led to a fundamental de- escalation and led to profound stabilization of the situation," the official said.
Asked if that is a disagreement with the Israeli stance, the U.S. official nodded.

OTOH only a few days ago, the messaging from the State Department had a somewhat different tone (not unlike what they have been saying about Russia, that it can stop the war [in Ukraine] at any time):

Nasrallah could stop the terrorist attacks across Israel. And I guarantee you, if he did that, we would be impressing upon Israel the need to maintain calm on their end. The bottom line is he hasn’t stopped those terrorist attacks. And so, as long as Hizballah is targeting – is launching terrorist attacks across the border, of course Israel is going to launch military action to defend itself, as any country would. What we continue to push to all the parties is not to escalate the conflict, not to let it spiral out of control into a war [...]

Anyhow, the US is now (together with some other, mostly Western countries) calling for a 21-ceasefire between Israel and Hezbollah/Lebanon. So, at least this a more concrete sense of de-escalation that they want, i.e. what happened in the past week with hundreds of dead (mostly in Lebanon) made Western capitals uncomfortable.
Also, I don't know how much credence or relevance to give (or place on) to this, as the White House refused to comment, but according to Woodward's most recent (War) book, Biden swears at Netanyahu whenever the latter does something the US perceives as too escalatory.

US hardly fears Iran Why does this matter though? The question is whether the US wants Israel to escalate (or at least wants to give Israel the scope to escalate); whether the US fears Iran sees irrelevant.

@Allure: escalate what? If the US feared that Israel was going to conquer Lebanon or something like that, they probably reconsider the weapon packages, like they did vis-a-vis of Gaza when they suspended the shipment of the biggest bombs. https://www.bbc.com/news/articles/ckkg6x62z6wo

Escalate whatever it is that they don't want to escalate as linked in the OP? I am not sure what your question actually is.

@Allure: without knowing what the US 'red lines' are, it's hard to say if they could be enforced by limiting weapon packages, at this juncture. Israel already has enough matériel to kill a commander or two, which was the action mentioned in that piece.

@Allure: TBH that context (added by Reuters) might have been misleading as to what the US said to Israel. From the official summary of a more recent, similar exchange: "Secretary Austin highlighted that further escalation is not inevitable and that all countries in the region would benefit from a de-escalation in tensions, including through completing a Gaza ceasefire and hostage release deal." https://www.defense.gov/News/Releases/Release/Article/3860559/readout-of-secretary-of-defense-lloyd-j-austin-iiis-call-with-israeli-minister/

@Allure: i.e. no Israeli action was publicly called out by the US SecDef other than not finalizing the deal with Hamas, which is assumed will lower the overall temperature. (And even for that one, the public call was not that directed at one side.)

@Allure: "However, he also stressed that the unprecedented scale of U.S. support for Israel since October 7 should leave Iran, Lebanese Hizballah, and other Iranian-backed terrorist groups with no doubt about U.S. resolve." While that part doesn't have the word 'escalate' in it, it's basically suggesting that the US is determined to win any escalation contest, i.e. it's the classic message of escalation dominance.

@Allure The US showing escalation dominance is a threat to Iran, who funds and supports various groups in the region. Having no fear of Iran is a threat to Iran to encourage Iran to want to de-escalate and/or encourage Hezbollah to de-escalate. The US is basically telling Iran to either sit down and watch its investments go up in smoke, or, alternatively, it can have its own assets go up in smoke too. So, you can't really ask a broad question about Israel and the US without getting a broader picture of the involved parties.

Because if one side is fighting with only defensive  weapons there will never be any de-escalation. If one side is fighting with offensive weapons and the other side is only fighting with defensive weapons , other than a surrender by the other side, what   would ever motivate the side fighting with the offensive weapons to stop fighting? Or even stop them from getting more aggressive.   Some of the defensive weapons will fail and injure the defensive side, they  will be living in tremendous fear etc.  The side fighting with offensive weapons knows that they   have no chance of getting hurt etc. The only conceivable way such a war could end other than with surrender is if the side with defensive weapons goes on the offense too. Once it becomes a situation where both sides have what to lose by continuing the war the likelihood of them agreeing to do so becomes more of a reality. That is the type of de-escalation the US is looking for being that diplomatic efforts seem to have gotten nowhere.

I think the analogy is a boxing match where one punches and the other just blocks. Eventually the attacker will drop from exhaustion. The war equivalent is running out of weapons.

Hezbollah  has (had?) about 150,000 missiles. At the rate they are shooting them at Israel   since October (about ten to a hundred a day) they never would have run out

what would ever motivate the side fighting with the offensive weapons to stop fighting? They might stop if they find further attacks are pointless. Like say I have a stick and you are sitting in a metal cage. There's nothing stopping me from swinging, but it's wasting my time and energy.

That is part of the point. Hezbollah kept becoming increasingly aggressive when they found that "only" shooting ten missiles a day into Israel wasn't getting any real reaction. That is the escalation that needed to be avoided and can only be done with offensive weapons

Let's just look at the list cited in the Q:
"good" weapons

aid to Ukraine was largely antiaircraft / antitank weapons,

"bad" weapons

50 F-15 fighter jets, Advanced Medium Range Air-to-Air Missiles, or AMRAAMs, 120 mm tank ammunition and high explosive mortars and tactical vehicles

So one by one:

anti-aircraft:   Shooing down aircraft is not really relevant vs. Hizbollah or Iran which don't fly much of anything and esp. not into Israel.  Relevant in Ukraine.  Could be of use to Israel in the anti-drone/anti-rocket department, but Iron Dome is pretty good there, except against saturation tactics, which a US system might also struggle with.  Maybe there'll be future deliveries?

anti-tank:  Not really relevant vs. Hizbollah or Iran which don't field tanks anywhere near Israel.  Relevant in Ukraine.

F15:  if it came to a counter-strike on Iran, F15s would be relevant, yes.

AMRAAMs:  not all that sure in either case, since Hizbollah nor Iran fly much of anything.  But a strike force would want to be able to protect itself.  And maybe an insurance against other air forces' like Syria's.

120mm tank ammo:  not all that relevant wrt Iran.  Quite relevant if the IDF went into Lebanon to neutralize Hizbollah.

mortars:  same as tanks

tactical vehicles:  same as tanks.


Basically, the shopping list is different for two reasons:

The adversary forces and terrain of operation are not the same.  Ukraine defends itself on its own territory against tanks and aircraft and the air component has been negligible so far.  Remember that Israel is being targeted from Lebanese and Iran territory, not invaded.  Counter-striking Iran may involve flying 1500+ km each way, while a ground war against Hizbollah - if deemed useful to take out Hizbollah rockets - will involve IDF tanks vs Hizbollah's dismounted infantry and ATM missiles.  As well as likely F-15s.

Aid to Israel is not really all that US-domestically controversial at that level (countering Iran as opposed to Gaza operations), whereas NATO was really concerned with escalation risks wrt Russia (a nuclear power, remember), esp. at the start.  A lot of the stuff on the "bads" list has by now graduated to being deliverable to Ukraine as well.


If one wants to see controversy wrt aid to Israel, 2000 pounder dumb bombs are a much better place to start than this list.
Last, the "escalation risk calculus" quite likely looks different to the US wrt Ukraine as opposed to Israel.

with Ukraine, the escalation risk comes from - nuclear armed - Russia which has long rattled its sabers about all sorts of stuff wrt US and NATO aid.

with Israel, the US may instead perceive - correctly, or incorrectly - that the best approach is to arm Israel sufficiently to dissuade Hizbollah and Iranian adventurism.  While simultaneously talking down Israel from reacting too strongly ("goodies" may increase that leverage).



Hizbo regularly sends drones into Israel. Their last attack was a barrage of (~200) dumb rockets to overload the Iron Dome, followed by a wave of (~20) drones. The latter were too few to have a real chance given that they were aimed at distant targets in the center of Israel, so here was plenty of time to shoot them down. Israel claims to have destroyed 2x to 3x as many rockets before they were fired, probably to prevent the Dome from running out of ammo in the middle of the Hizbo salvos. They had that kind of experience on Oct 7, even if that was a less mediatized aspect of that event.

Are you saying AMRAAMs will be used to hunt drones?  "Fly much of anything" obviously referred to a regular air force, it's well known Hizbollah uses missiles, drones to carry out cross-border attacks.

"while a ground war against Hizbollah - if deemed useful" -- the US so far has publically dissuaded that, reasoning that it would prompt an Iranian intervention like in Syria https://www.axios.com/2024/06/06/biden-israel-lebanon-war-iran-intervention

Well, it's pretty obvious that the US government doesn't decide whether or not an incursion into Lebanon is useful or not, that's decided by the Israeli government.

Ultimately true, but the Q is what does a sponsor country like the US do when an ally does something they (the US) [say they] don't want to happen. Do they still given them all the toys and hope for the best, or ... https://www.bbc.com/news/articles/ckkg6x62z6wo

And yeah Ukrainians have been shooting Shahed drones with NASAMs "like crazy" https://www.pravda.com.ua/eng/news/2023/01/1/7383193/ And NASAMs are basically ground-launched AMRAAMS. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NASAMS They also adapted the older AIM-7 Sparrow to be launched from the ground in the 'FrankenSAM' projects https://www.twz.com/frankensam-systems-are-now-shooting-down-drones-in-ukraine

The problem for Ukraine is that AMRAAMS/NASAMS are far more expensive than Israeli iron dome interceptors (Tamir/SkyHunter) https://www.nytimes.com/2023/01/03/world/europe/ukraine-russia-drones.html Israel wasn't willing to have these supplied to  Ukraine. I'm not sure if the US manufacturing them in the future, which they are going to do https://insidedefense.com/insider/new-arkansas-facility-will-begin-producing-skyhunter-interceptors-early-2026 is going to change that, given IP rights etc.

@MakeStackExchangeGREAT4ever I am not sure why you have to spend so much time qualifying this answer.  Is it to inform me of stuff?  Is it to inform other readers?  AMRAAMs do not correspond to Iron Dome, at many, many levels.  That's rather obvious and this answer never claimed they did.  The one part where AMRAAMs are mentioned - because the OP's question did - makes it clear (relatively) it has to do with aircraft vs aircraft.  No need to get lost in the commenting weeds, esp not on a month-old answer.  Just to be clear:  I don't need another comment explaining why you had to comment.

They have already enough defensive weapons, but it's not enough. Sometimes they need to destroy terrorists infrastructure. We know that Hamas and Hezbollah have an extensive  network of tunnels, they use them for firing rockets and hiding their troops.
If there are heavy attacks, the defense system gets saturated and cannot neutralize all rockets.

Looks like one of the premises to the question is wrong.
Source

While Biden and Harris would be eager to avoid all-out war and the impression of chaos, few believe that the US administration would take major steps against Israel, with the political risks involved, so close to the election.
...
James Jeffrey, a former US ambassador to Iraq and Turkey who takes a hard line on Iran, said that US policymakers instinctively promoted ceasefires but that Netanyahu, like Ukrainian President Volodymyr Zelensky, was more concerned about his country's security.

The article goes on to say that withholding military aid to Israel would be the "ultimate leverage", but Biden has largely held off on doing it, and the muted US response to Israeli actions like killing Ismail Haniyeh presumably emboldens Israel.
So it seems like the explanation is:

The US doesn't actually want de-escalation, because there is a significant fraction of the country that does not think Israel should de-escalate (or thinks that Israel is not the party that is escalating). Because the country is democratic, this in turn forces the country's leadership to act similarly.
The US says they want de-escalation anyway, for "instinctive" reasons (presumably the same reason why some people automatically equate 'escalate' with 'undesirable' and 'peace' with 'desirable').


There are some incorrect assumptions in the question. Currently, there are 1 million Israeli refugees from the northern parts of Israel (per UN approved borders) because of dozens of deaths and large scale destruction due to Hezbollah missile attacks from southern Lebanon over the past year. So it is not true that Israel initiated a "pre-emptive cross border strike with Hezbollah".
None of the weapons that the U.S. will be selling (not "providing" or giving) to Israel will be manufactured and ready for delivery until some time in 2026 at the earliest, per the Associated Press article cited by OP. From the same article, which is up to date, the 50 F-15 fighter jets will not be ready for delivery until 2029. That suggests the U.S. is not escalating the current conflict. (This is conjecture, but perhaps the promised armaments are offered with the intent to kick the can down the road to not only the next administration, but possibly the one after that. It wouldn't be unknown for the U.S. as it has done so in the case of other conflicts and other nations.)
In addition, U.S. allies such as Germany have sharply curtailed their weapons sales to Israel. For example, Germany sold $363 million of military equipment and war weapons to Israel in 2023, but has only agreed to sales of $32,000 (a 10,000 fold decrease) in 2024 according Reuters as of September 2024. France, another U.S. ally, has banned all weapons sales to Israel, and will not allow any Israeli to attend French arms manufacturer conventions. So, the U.S. is clearly not pressuring its allies to support Israel.
In contrast, with Ukraine, delivery of money (e.g. Janet Yellen flew to Kiev to present Zelensky with a check from the U.S. Treasury for $1 billion in person) and weapons has been carried out with great urgency. The U.S. has depleted its own stock of HIMARs, Javelins, and maybe even Abrams tanks. The U.S. has even been sending 155 mm ammo that it seized from stateless dhows in the Persian Gulf directly to Ukraine.
Also, the U.S. and then Germany and the UK were sending much more than anti-aircraft and other defensive weapons to Ukraine in less than a year of the Russian Special Military Operation. Specifically, they were giving (under lend-lease and immediately, out of existing stockpiles) Abrams and Leopard tanks, respectively.
That is quite a contrast. It would seem that the US IS encouraging de-escalation in Israel, but was not in Ukraine.

This is misleading at the very least. The US has provided plenty of weapons to Israel during this conflict. Albeit the Biden administration has often attempted to conceal the extent of the deliveries, due to split opinions on those in his constituency.

"The under-the-radar deliveries made by the Biden administration to Israel were additional to the three major military sales that were made public since the start of the war: $320m in precision bomb kits in November and 14,000 tank shells costing $106m and $147.5m of fuses and other components needed to make 155mm artillery shells in December. The December deliveries of tank and artillery shells also sidestepped congressional scrutiny because they were made under an emergency authority." Why emergency if for 2026?

"between the start of Gaza war last October and the end of June, the US has transferred at least 14,000 of the MK-84 2,000lb bombs, 6,500 500lb bombs, 3,000 Hellfire precision-guided air-to-ground missiles, 1,000 bunker-buster bombs, 2,600 air-dropped small-diameter bombs and other munitions." https://www.theguardian.com/world/article/2024/jul/10/biden-resumes-sending-israel-bombs

Aside, the whole European (mostly German) shtick of supplying weapons only between rounds of fighting is nothing but hypocrisy really. The Q wasn't about Germany anyhow.

@IVFcomesfromthetip I only mentioned Germany because the U.S. pressures its allies to go along with what it wants. The question included Ukraine, and it has become clearer recently that Germany (both people and Scholz) are not eager to keep supporting Zelensky, let alone helping Ukraine make incursions into Russian territory e.g. Kursk.

@IVFcomesfromthetip You're right about those 2000 pound bombs. I read something unconvincing in Janes they aren't so effective and wondered, if true, then why use them? Your comment is interesting because the amounts sum to less than a billion dollars, which is so much less than the $174 bil to Ukraine (it isn't all weapons, I realize.)  What you said about Biden's constituency is true, and amusing, because he (well, Democrats/Kamala) will likely get at least 70% of the Jewish vote, and a much smaller number among other Americans including some Christians and Muslims.

In general, I always avoid answering Israel-related questions because there is no room for free expression when it goes against Israel—serial downvotes and delete-votes will haunt my answer the moment it is posted.
Anyway, still, I will try.

There've been several news sources of how the US is trying to get Israel / Hamas / Hezbollah / Iran to de-escalate (example).

The USA is neither trying to escalate nor trying to deescalate. The USA is just managing the situation that Israel has created.
Pro-Israel Americans want a relentless supply of US weapons to Israel to decisively defeat Hamas, Hezbollah, or any other opposing forces so that Israel can exist as a peaceful home for pro-Israel people and reigh supreme on its neighbors.
On the other hand, the US government has to keep a delicate balance between its supply of weapons to Israel and its human rights, free speech, Arab friendliness, and other facades. So, the US government is caught in the middle.
In an ideal situation, though, the US would be happy if the situation descalated because this situation is harming the US's proxy war between Ukraine and Russia in the sense that the US government has to work overtime. However, the US is managing both wars very well due to its global network of arms supply—even countries Pakistan is supplying arms for the USA.
I suppose the USA would have sent boots on the ground if there were no Ukraine-Russia war. However, they seems to be avoiding two large-scale wars at the same time.

This site is not a forum to express your controversial and incorrect opinions (in fact, opinions at all), if you got the wrong idea somehow.

Well, the overtime thing sure is ... true? https://youtu.be/B3PLqfnLlOk?t=61

There are three currents here. One is that Israel is the US proxy in the Middle East and the second is the strength of the Israeli lobby in the US. The third is the Israeli fear of its neighbours which it argues it means it must arm itself to the teeth. The three have butressed US policy in the Middle East ever since Israel declared itself a state and has ensured that US guarantees the strength of the Israeli military.
The US, if it wished to de-escalate the situation the situation in the Middle East could simply stop the flow of military funds to Israel. This would viscerally send a signal to Israel the extent of US displeasure. Instead, it wrings its hands and engages in mealy mouthed platitudes.

"if it wished to de-escalate the situation the situation in the Middle East could simply stop the flow of military funds to Israel". Not my DV, but I doubt that would work as you describe at this point. More likely Iran and proxies would think they're more likely to win. Israel has enough stuff of domestic production to pound Gaza. And their farther right-wing will have no qualms about employing extreme strategies anymore. Did you read about the "generals' plan" to declare a formal siege? Meaning no food, supplies etc. whatsoever?

And anyone left is a fair target https://www.timesofisrael.com/liveblog_entry/netanyahu-tells-lawmakers-hes-considering-generals-plan-to-lay-siege-to-northern-gaza/

US simply lies, or let me put it another way, US simply changes the meaning of words the way it likes. De-escalation happens if our battle side is superior, otherwise we, the US, continue escalation until other sides will give up and we are again superior.
According to here, the British-Israeli historian Avi Shlaim, once with reference to Israel’s continuing colonization of the West Bank said: “Netanyahu is like a man who, while negotiating the division of a pizza, continues to eat it”. US is not different in logic. It gives munition to any side of the war, and encourage it allies to do so, and then blame anyone who gives munition to the other side, encouraging EVERYONE (obviously excluding themselves) to de-escalation. You can see the same routine also in Russia-Ukraine war. If someone helps Russia, US will say you have make life for Ukrainian people harder and more tragic, but if it gives munition to Ukraine to be able to continue withstanding against Russia on behalf of US and its allies that would be interpreted as helping the Ukrainian people. It is this logic that made the Polish MEP say "Blinken, go home! As soon as possible! Get out of here! We don't want you here. We don't want Poles to pay and die for your wars!" Therefore, all such sayings are hypocrisy, good looking lies to make people easily accept they care for values that people care much. Once an American activist expressed his surprise in response to US sorrow about ceasefire agreement not being successful, saying US pretends to be deeply worried like an outsider third-party which has not itself been highly active in the war, like it could not prevent all these tragedies by simply not sending munitions to Israel.

"De-escalation happens if our battle side is superior". There's even a name for that "escalate to deescalate". And since you brought up Ukraine, Russia allegedly does employ that strat too. Wanna join NATO? Pre-emptive invasion [when feasible].

As for the Polish MEP, isn't that the self-made firefighter guy who put out some Hanukkah candles? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5-P4opDdIcw IIRC he's extremely pro-Russia, which is not typical of the Polish. But I'm not surprised he'd have fans in Iran too. OTOH that he was able to say those things proves that Poland still has some democracy left...

@MakeStackExchangeGREAT4ever, Thanks for teaching me the name foe that strat., and yes you are right, Russia seems to behave the same when possible. Even We in Iran do the same, and it is even in Quran that teaches Muslims to do the same, although how to do it might be an issue for debate, like mass-killing munition are forbidden in Islam as far as the scholars have understood.

But as for the Polish MEP, I doubt people not engaged in Politics have know his name at all, and people if have ever heard his name that would be for such speeches that he gives. To People in Iran, what he said in that speech is the very truth behind US meddling anywhere in the world, in any name. Also people now have accepted that the governments are the majority of their people are not always on the same side about all the issues, and being Pro-Palestine/Pro-Israel is perhaps one bold issue they in many cases think differently about.

There are plenty of Americans that aren't pro-Ukraine! It hasn't been the majority of the electorate for over a year.

@EllieK, sorry, It was not meant to talk about US citizens, but the government.

@owari No problem, and no need to apologize, but you are kind to do so! I mostly wanted you to know that I read your comments and and answer, appreciated and concurred with lots of both.

@IVFcomesfromthetip Thanks for sharing the video. He's an MP, and was yelling loudly that that Judaism and Jews are satanic in Poland's parliament building. Doesn't seem democratic to make a unilateral decision. Also, it isn't a sign of democracy to have an MP with a fire extinguisher blast a group of people with CO2 and call them satanic in parliament. Some of them might be his constituents. There ARE Polish Jews who live in Poland. He's pro-Russian but that wouldn't happen in Russia, despite not being a democracy.
