How are those opposed to Ukraine hitting Russian airfields with Western-supplied weapons arguing Ukraine should deal with glide bombs?
In year three of the war, Russia has managed to make its tactical aviation pretty useful for making territorial gains, thanks to turning their planes into launch platforms for guided glide bombs.

Russia has accelerated its destruction of Ukraine’s front-line cities in 2024 to a scale previously unseen in the war using the glide bombs and an expanding network of airstrips, according to an Associated Press analysis of drone footage, satellite imagery, Ukrainian documents and Russian photos.
The results can be seen in the intensity of recent Russian attacks. It took a year for Russia to obliterate Bakhmut, where the bombs were first used. That was followed by destruction in Avdiivka that took months. Then, only weeks were needed to do the same in Vovchansk and Chasiv Yar, according to images analyzed by AP that showed the smoldering ruins of both cities.

While for artillery at least the West at least appears to have a generally agreed plan (albeit seemingly lagging behind in execution), I'm not sure what--if anything--they plan to do to against the advantage that Russia has in glide bombs.
My impression is that most Western politicians don't seem to consider allowing Ukraine to hit Russian airfields (typically located at least 100km from the front line) with Western-supplied weapons. (Except in Crimea.) Some (retired) Western officers, e.g. gen. Breedlove [USAF/SACEUR] even suggested that this is going to lose the war for Ukraine. While Ukraine has sometimes managed to hit Russian airfields with locally assembled weapons, this doesn't seem to slow down the Russian air force enough. (The US assessed in April that Russia lost around 10% of its air force [since the war started], but almost none of its strategic aviation.)
And it's also a matter of scale, according to Ukraine's president (Aug 22 statement):

Russia has fired around 10,000 missiles and over 33,000 glide bombs at Ukraine since it started its full-scale invasion in February 2022, President Volodymyr Zelenskiy said in social media posts on Sunday.

And so he seems to rule out shooting them [bombs] down directly:

However, even more Patriot missile batteries would not solve the glide-bomb problem, Zelenskyy said.
“A Patriot missile costs some $3 million. We would not be able to have thousands of such missiles or even hundreds. No one can produce that many. You might win in the short term, but Russians will still exhaust your missile stocks and then keep bombing cities and energy infrastructure as usual,” Zelenskyy said.
The best solution is allowing Ukraine to use longer-range ATACMS to destroy Russian bombers on airfields far from Ukraine’s border, Zelenskyy added.

(For a cost comparison a glide-guidance kit, assuming you've produced the 'dumb' bomb already--and Russia seems to have ample stockpiles--reportedly costs around $25K.)
So, what do politicians who reject the idea of Western weapons hitting air fields in the depth of Russian territory suggest Ukraine or the West should do against the more effective Russian air force of 2024 (other than suggesting Ukraine negotiate peace with Russia, which some have suggested as the only plausible avenue)?
(That last piece also mentions [as one of the reasons why Ukraine has to negotiate] that the US only makes around 600 Patriot missiles per year.)

Sometimes you just deal with that your opponent has certain advantages you can't easily counter.

This question feels like whataboutism.

@ohwilleke: about what??

"How can critics of X have an issue with marginally related issue Y?"

@ohwilleke: I still don't get what you're trying to say. What are X and Y here? I guess your point is that those who oppose Western weapons use in Russia shouldn't have to say anything about how Ukraine is supposed to deal with Russian air-force or glide bombs? [I mean, sure that's true for those who just want Ukraine to negotiate instead of fighting, but I'm not really interested in that obviousness, as I
made clear.]

@MakeStackExchangeGREAT4ever I am taking your headline question and putting it into a more general form. X opposition to using Western weapons to attack insider Russia is only marginally related to dealing with Russian glide bombs in Ukraine.

@ohwilleke: you're welcome to edit the title. I'm interested in those like e.g. the US administration which don't seem to encourage Ukraine to negotiate [publicly anyway--saying Ukraine sets their own goals etc.] but also don't want Ukraine to hit any airbases deep in Russia [with US weapons]. But that might be too narrow, as they (the adm.) might not have said anything in public (even when pressed by some journalist--they might have punted with some bland generality.)

@ohwilleke, I think this is not whataboutism. The problem with the question is that it assumes Ukraine is entitled to any Western weapons it needs, and that the refusal to hand them over must be justified. The default state in international relations is that states do not simply hand out weapons with no strings attached.

@o.m.: I did not claim they are 'entitled'. But they already have (i.e. were given) Storm Shadows & ATACMS that have the range but none of those weapons hit any Russian airfields except in Crimea (where the Western countries said it's okay to strike in-depth). So the Q is about the Western use rules. BTW, I'm not sure if any advocates of non-escalation predicted that Ukraine would go for a ground offensive [in Kursk] as a possible way to close the distance to some such objectives.

Would you accept "Ukraine should make peace" as an answer?

@Allure: it's an obvious answer, which I've already mentioned in the Q albeit just as 'negotiate'. The piece clearly means they should negotiate... peace.

Funny that the Q was closed just as there was news that Lloyd Austin said something in response.

@ohwilleke "This question feels like whataboutism." True, but what about all the other questions of the same type that exist here. :) It's not the first such one.

@NoDataDumpNoContribution Sure. I do my best to catch such questions, but I don't have infinite resources of time.

Voting to reopen - The question isn't bad and has an accepted answer. Let's leave it at that.

Obviously there are different opponents to arms use, with different reasons and explanations.

Some believe that NATO should provide Ukraine with all the support which does not trigger WWIII. If that is not enough to save Ukraine, that would be unfortunate but cannot be helped.
The problem with this position is of course knowing what would trigger a Russian escalation. Russian propagandists have long claimed that the West is fighting Russia, to the point that a day without nuclear threats by any Kremlin-affilated speaker would be newsworthy. So going by Russian public statements is pointless. There is a habit of doing certain deliveries together, and incrementally, to slowly normalize them. For instance, Germany refused to release Leopards until the US promised to deliver Abrams.
A variant of this line is that Ukraine can and should attack Russian airfields with domestically produced drones and missiles, while using imports on Ukrainian territory.
That would be an easy solution if the weapons are really interchangeable for the mission. Airfields are often attacked with cluster munitions, which are harder to improvise than unitary warheads. Note that Crimea is internationally recognized as Ukrainian territory -- it is not a question of distances behind the frontline, it is a question of legitimate borders.
Some say that Russia has legitimate security interests which were violated by the West. So they are against helping Ukraine fight in any way.
This position tends to mingle with opposition to the present government in their homelands, so it is hard to tell if they really believe the Russian position or if they are simply supporting the enemy of their true enemy (liberals in their homeland). Some individuals have been bribed by Russia, too. Hard to tell just how deep this goes in their respective parties.
Some believe that war is not the solution under any circumstances, and that letting Russia occupy Ukraine until there is some future democratic reform in Russia is the lesser evil.
Just going by the numbers, more humans die on the frontlines than under Russian occupation. So a position which values every single human life above all other considerations is against arms deliveries.


"it is not a question of distances behind the frontline, it is a question of legitimate borders". Only to some extent now. They were given permission to use HIMARS GMLRS to hit some 60km inside Russia if needed, this spring. BTW, the initial strategy of "no strikes across the Yalu" worked to some extent in the original setting too. So if the goal is to give half of Ukraine to Russia...

Anyhow, Lloyd Austin did indeed recently say something like this. "There are a lot of targets in Russia - big country, obviously," Austin said. "And there's a lot of capability that Ukraine has in terms of UAVs (unmanned aerial vehicles) and other things to address those targets." https://www.reuters.com/world/biden-sign-250-million-ukraine-security-assistance-2024-09-06/ So, I'm accepting this answer as roughly the only kind of answer given for now.

TBH that seems to be a bit of a softening of "if Ukraine falls, I really believe that NATO will be in a fight with Russia" https://www.newsweek.com/nato-will-drawn-war-russia-if-ukraine-loses-lloyd-austin-1874913"

I put this as a comment first, but it is actually an answer from a notable source. US SecDef Austin was quoted & paraphrased saying that:

Russia had already moved aircraft that launch glide bombs into Ukraine beyond the range of U.S.-supplied ATACM missiles.
"There's no one capability that will in and of itself be decisive in this campaign," Austin told reporters at the end of the meeting.
He also said Ukraine had capabilities of its own - such as drones - to hit targets inside Russia that were beyond the reach of ATACM and British-supplied Storm Shadow missiles.
"There are a lot of targets in Russia - big country, obviously," Austin said. "And there's a lot of capability that Ukraine has in terms of UAVs (unmanned aerial vehicles) and other things to address those targets."

In other words, Austin thinks it would be more trouble than worth (for the US) to give that permission. The latter half of that is perhaps also an allusion to the US opposition to Ukraine hitting Russian refineries etc. One might be able to read between the lines that Ukraine should instead focus all their long range droning on purely military targets, such as airfields, for which it would have more drones [to hit with] if some were not sent elsewhere.
Also, FWTW, Putin has recently reiterated that if NATO gives such permission, he'll consider Russia at war with NATO.
Also, according to CNN:

US intelligence believes 90% of Russian aircraft that launch deadly glide bombs (at least 100 per day, according to Zelensky), are more than 300 kilometers (186 miles) from Ukrainian-controlled territory, so outside of ATACMS range. And that number may be increasing. Russia recently relocated planes from two bases near the border further east, according to one US official.


And then:

The United States has agreed to give Ukraine $800 million in military aid that will go toward manufacturing long-range drones to use against Russian troops, Ukraine’s leader said on Monday, fulfilling a longtime Ukrainian goal of getting Washington to buy weapons from manufacturers in Ukraine instead of primarily in America.
A Pentagon official, speaking anonymously because of the sensitivity of the issue, confirmed the move, which comes as the United States shifts its policy and moves toward shoring up Ukraine’s ability to fight the war with its own weapons and on its own terms.
The decision to support long-range drone production in Ukraine may be a kind of consolation prize for Mr. Zelensky, who — despite repeated pleas — has so far failed to persuade Western partners to lift restrictions on using their long-range missiles to strike deep inside Russia.


This is a good answer, from an authoritative source. I like the accepted answer too. Over a month later, it seems to hold up.

Ukraine is supposed to shot the bombs down with the help of air defenses that were sent there. That's why it is said that "sending of SAM batteries doesn't make us part of this war because it is a defensive weapon and self-defense is allowed by UN".
Syria is in roughly the same situation: Israel periodically bombs Damascus but Syrian air defenses only shoot at the missiles and never at the fighters that launch them.
BTW, it is a big mistake to think that long-range weapons can help against gliding bombs. Russian forces can strike anywhere they like but Ukrainian forces still successfully use JDAM and "Hammer".

Wrong reasoning. In defensive wars, one is allowed to take tactically and strategically offensive action as long as that meets the standards of distiction, necessity and proportionality from the laws of war.

Not my DV, but these are even harder to target and cheaper than Shadeds. They have hi-low flight profile due to their unpowered descent. And the lack of motor means virtually no heat signature to lock on. So probably only something like the Iron Dome would work against these, and Ukraine doesn't have anything like that (it uses hi-powered radars too, which Russia would easily target by their emissions.) Anyway, my Q was if any politician has said this is how Ukraine should deal with them, but this seems to be just your suggestion.

(Totally aside, but although Iran has provided Hezbollah with some interesting weapons like the 358 missile, they don't seem to have given them any anti-radiation missiles that would pose a serious threat to the Iron Dome. Whether that's because Iran hasn't mastered the tech or something else, IDK.)

Somewhat related BTW https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/88834/if-the-us-wishes-for-de-escalation-why-doesnt-it-provide-israel-with-only-defe

@o.m. Do you suggest that during Iraq war it was ok to blow up Pentagon or sink some USA military transports in Atlantic and Hussein didn't do that only because they were weaker than al-Qaeda...?

@user13964273, the Iraq war is a bad example because of UNSC resolutions. But generally, the US has no right to expect that their homeland is a sanctuary while they bomb elsewhere.

@MakeStackExchangeGREAT4ever Yes, this is nothing but an educated guess but this answer is obvious enough to be right and too unpleasant for any official politician to say it in loud. BTW, a gliding bomb is falling by (almost) ordinary ballistic trajectory and thus is not harder to intercept than any other ballistic target (using radar guidance). Ukraine reported enough intercepted ballistic Iskander missiles so the only problem with gliding FABs is their mass usage on frontline while most of SAM sites are around Kyiv. Still there is a video in the Net of a bomb's interception over Kharkov.
